# Confusing Physics question. Please help!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

A small city requires about 10 MW of power. Suppose that instead of using high-voltage lines to supply the power, the power is delivered at 120 V.

Assuming a two-wire line of 0.56 −cm -diameter copper wire, estimate the cost of the energy lost to heat per hour per meter. Assume the cost of electricity is about 10 cents per kWh.

First, I found the area = pi*r^2 = pi*(.56*10^-2/2)^2 = 7.84 * 10^-6 m2

Then I found R = 1.72 * 10^-8/7.84 * 10^-6 m2 = 2190 µΩ --> double that, and I get 4388 µΩ = 4.388 mΩ  (because resistance of two wires is twice of that)

Current = 10 MW/120v = 83.3 kA

power lost in the wire
P = I²R = (83.3 kA)²(4.388 mΩ) = 3.04e4 watts = 30.4 MW
is what I'm doing so far correct? I multiplied 30.4 MW by the the cost of electricity and I got the wrong answer. I'm so confused. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> 3.04e4 watts = 30.4 MW

It doesn't